# Using MPI I/O in hybrid MPI/OpenMP program

Tags: c, performance, io, mpi, openmp

I'm converting an existing MPI code to a hybrid MPI/OpenMP for performance and scalability issues. In the original MPI code I have used collective MPI I/O (specifically MPI_File_write/read_at_all) and now that I'm converting it to the hybrid mode I don't know how to work with I/O without loosing the performance. The system that I currently use has multiple nodes of 32 cores and my plan is to run 1 MPI process per each node and 32 threads inside each node. The system and compiler (PGI) support MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE and has a Lustre-based parallel file system. My code is something like:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include "omp.h"
#define NTHREADS 32
int main()
{
    int provided;
    int myrank,numproc,tid;
    double b[BIGSIZE]={0.};
    int iter,i;

    MPI_Init_thread( 0, 0, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided );
    omp_set_num_threads(NTHREADS);

    /* Initialize b */

    #pragma omp parallel private(i,some variables)\
                         shared(b and some other stuffs)\
                         default(none)
    {
        /* Inside each thread: */
        for (i=0;i<iter;i++)
        {
            /* each thread of each process do work on few elements of variable b */
            /* 2 threads do less work and communicate with the other processes  */
            /* Write the variable b's of all MPI processes in one file */
            /* b is actually divided between MPI processes and then is divided
               between threads inside each process, so the work is distributed */
            /* write operation MUST be complete before the next iteration starts */
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Now my question is how to handle the write section to obtain the best performance, I'm a mechanical engineer so am not familiar with the possible solutions. Before I start to work on this I wanted to see if there is a standard way for similar cases, My ideas are:

1. Use MPI_File_write_at inside each thread and forget about collective version, (I'm not sure if this is really correct, can I use MPI_Barrier and omp_barrier to wait for the completion?), how would I define file pointer? private or shared?
2. Use MPI_File_write_at_all in the master thread in a master directive and keep the rest of threads idle using a barrier.
3. Any other possible way?

The performance and scalability of the code are really critical for me and I need some help from you guys please!

Thanks

Comment: Just a side question, which MPI implementation do you use?

Comment: I use mvapich2 with pgi c compiler

Answer (score 2):

I think you're prematurely optimizing for problems you might not have.

Start by making the computation parallel with OpenMP, stick in some OpenMP barriers and carry on doing IO as you were before.

Benchmark / time that code and, if the IO turns out to be a big barrier to performance, try to optimize. You might find that the things you're suggesting actually give worse performance than the collective versions. Either way, get a quantitative handle on your current performance before optimizing.

If you're desperate for speed, one of the fastest and easiest things you can do is to write each thread to a separate file then combine the files in post-processing. I find this pretty hacky, so would leave it as a last resort.

Comment: +1. OP: You probably don't want 32 threads/processes per node writing to disk at once anyway; you likely only have one pipe to the FS per node, and 32 tasks contending for FS is probably bad for performance.  Maybe 1 task won't make full use of that the connection; but easiest way to deal with that is to experiment with having 2 or more MPI tasks per node, which is often good for NUMA performance, etc.  @hbcdev is absolutely right; while these issues are worth keeping in mind, they're not worth architecting around yet until you start getting some real data in and see what the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Jonathan, of course you know if he uses collective I/O concerns like "how many on-node tasks fight for I/O" get optimized (in most MPI-IO implementations) when  two-phase selects aggregators.

Comment: thanks guys I put it for the master thread and it works well now.